# Java JUnit, result not changing when updated

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, automated-tests

I am currently writing some unit test for my Java 8 code. And I have a problem.

In the code below, you can see 3 test functions the first one returns 6 which is correct. However, the second one does also return 6 even though it should return 16, and the third also return 6 even though it should return 21.

And if I comment out the first function the second returns 16 which is correct. But now the third function is returning 16 instead of 6, where it should return 21.

The code I am testing is a Static Class.

```
@Test
public void testRun1() {
    Integer[][] input = {
        {6},
        {6, 6},
        {5, 6},
        {4, 6},
        {3, 6},
        {2, 6},
        {1, 6},
    };
    int expResult = 6;
    int result = BoardingTest.Run(input);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}

@Test
public void testRun2() {     
    Integer[][] input = new Integer[][]{
        {6},
        {6, 6},
        {6, 4},
        {5, 6},
        {3, 8},
        {1, 9},
        {2, 1},
    };
    int expResult = 16;
    int result = instance.Run(input);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}

@Test
public void testRun3() {
    Integer[][] input = new Integer[][]{
        {6},
        {1, 1},
        {2, 2},
        {3, 3},
        {4, 4},
        {5, 5},
        {6, 6},
    };
    int expResult = 21;
    int result = BoardingTest.Run(input);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

The code for Run is in a Class Called BoardingTest and is as following.

```
public class BoardingTest {
// N
static int N;
// Total number of passengers seated
static int Seated = 0;
// Total time
static int TotalTime = 0;
// Shortest time for a passanger who is in the act of sitting down
static int ShortestTime = 999999;
// 1.st dimension = Seat, 2.nd = Time
static int[][] Passengers;
// Current passenger
static int Passenger = 0;
// The first seat that a person is in the act of sitting down in
static int FirstOccupied = 999999;
// Refference to the passenger who is in the act of sitting in the plane
static ArrayList<Integer> Plane = new ArrayList<Integer>();

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

}

public static int Run(Integer[][] input){

    GetInput(input);

    // Loop untill all passengers is seated
    while(Seated < N){
        Tick();
    }

    return(TotalTime);
}

// Reads all input
private static void GetInput (Integer[][] input){
    N = input[0][0];

    Passengers = new int[N][2];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        SplitInput(i, input);
    }
}

// Splits an inputline into Seat and Time
private static void SplitInput(int i, Integer[][] input){
    Passengers[i][0] = input[i+1][0];
    Passengers[i][1] = input[i+1][1];
}

// This handels what happens in a Tick
private static void Tick(){
    // Keep putting passengers into the plane, until we can't do that anymore
    InserPassengers();

    TotalTime += ShortestTime;
    // Remove 1 sec from all passangers in the plane
    boolean removeOne = RemoveTimeFromPassengersInPlae(ShortestTime);

    // If someone was removed, find the new FirstOccupied seat
    if(removeOne){
        FirstOccupied = FindFirstOccupiedSeat();
    }

    // End Tick
}

// Will insert as many passengers as posible into the plane
private static void InserPassengers(){
    while(Passenger != N && FirstOccupied > Passengers[Passenger][0]){
        // If this passengers takes les time to sit, update ShortestTime
        if(Passengers[Passenger][1] < ShortestTime){
            ShortestTime = Passengers[Passenger][1];
        }

        // Add this passenger to the plane
        Plane.add(Passenger);

        // Set FisrstOccupied
        FirstOccupied = Passengers[Passenger][0];

        // Increase the Passenger number
        Passenger++;
    }
}

// Will find the Fist Occupied seat
private static int FindFirstOccupiedSeat(){
    int result = 999999;
    for(Integer i : Plane){
        if(Passengers[i][0] < result){
            result = Passengers[i][0];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Will remove some time from everyone in the plane
// And remove everyone who has finished sitting down
// And find the shortest time for the next one to sit
private static boolean RemoveTimeFromPassengersInPlae(int time){
    ShortestTime = 999999;
    boolean removed = false;

    for(int i = Plane.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        // Remove time
        Passengers[Plane.get(i)][1] -= time;

        // If time is 0
        //  Remove Passanger
        if(Passengers[Plane.get(i)][1] == 0){
            Plane.remove(i);
            removed = true;
            Seated++;
        }
        // Set new Shortes Time
        else if(Passengers[Plane.get(i)][1] < ShortestTime){
            ShortestTime = Passengers[Plane.get(i)][1];
        }
    }

    return removed;
}

private static void Print(String s){
    System.out.println(s);
}
private static void Print(int i){
    System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of the relevant `Run` method(s).

Comment: Seeing as there is no other information, I conclude that `BoardingTest.Run` implemented something like this: `return input[1][1] == 6 ? 6 : 16`.

Comment: Hint: if you test code is correct, but method under test returns something which fails the test, then you have a bug in method under test, and this bug should be fixed.

Comment: Okay now I have added the code for Run. 
And my problem is not that the code returns something wrong. The problem is that when I run the tests the variable `result´ is not updated to the correct value in the tests after test1. If it is because the values for the static class does not change or something I have don’t know.

Comment: Please read (and follow) the 
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after playing for at bit I found the problem.

It is because the class I call is static.

And correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that static variables do not change when calling the same static class multiple times.

Comment: static variable are **class level variables**, means irrespective of how many objects you create for a class, all static variables of the class are **shared by all the objects**. Only one copy exists. 

So, incase, you update the static variable by one object or first call, the second call will see the updated value (most of the cases see more on **volatile** keyword and **thread safety** which i am not considering here)

So, if may happen that first time you update a static variable static int N = 5, next call will see its value as 5.